# Trying to test an Android module in MultiDex app, com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner is not recognized

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, android-multidex, android-studio-2.0

Does someone have any idea why i can not use the MultiDexTestRunner ?

[image: Instrumentation runner class not specified]

my build.gradle contains :

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner'
    }

dependencies {
...
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Gradle's Android plugin is version 2.0.0-alpha2 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2)

```
//Runs all unit tests.
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ACLTest.class})
public class UnitTestSuite {

    public UnitTestSuite() {}
}
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class ACLTest {

    static Context context;

    public ACLTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        ...
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpBeforeTest() throws Exception {
      ...
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void aAGetInstance() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your application should extends MultiDexApplication from dex-support lib>?

Comment: @OrestSavchak the application already does. But what i am trying to do is use unit tests in one of the modules of the project.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by implementing an extension to android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner and override onCreate

```
public class MultiDexAndroidJUnitRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        //To make it work on MultiDex environment.
        //https://plus.google.com/+OleksandrKucherenko/posts/i7qZdVEy3Ue
        MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());

        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. But how to use it? I'm trying to use it in @RunWith annotation, but it doesn't work/

Comment: I've found. I need to set it in testInstrumentationRunner in build.gradle.

Comment: I'm in the same context, but with Espresso, and this do not solve the problem : i get a :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest FAILED. Any hint ? @tse